# How to handle python suds return return body[0].children

Tags: python, api, soap, suds, navision

I'm building a backend process using python+suds that is connecting to MS Navision 2009 R2 web services(SOAP api).

So far all is good, here's what I've got for starters:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated
ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='***\\***', password='*******')
url = 'http://host:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/company/Page/Serial_Number_Information'
client = Client(url, transport=ntlm)
print (client)
try:
  result = client.service.Read(' ', ' ', 'value')
except WebFault, e:
  print e


print (result)
```

I'm running into a scenario where the following SOAP reply:

```
<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Soap:Body/>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

is causing my process to throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
result = self.send(soapenv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 647, in send
result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 684, in succeeded
reply, result = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 153, in get_reply
nodes = self.replycontent(method, soapbody)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/bindings/document.py", line 75, in replycontent
return body[0].children
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'
```

I've tried

```
if not result:
  foo
```

and

```
if not key in result:
  foo
```

I'm not sure how to trap and move on from this error.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.  Added a second "except"

```
try:
  result = client.service.Read(' ', ' ', 'value')
except WebFault, e:
  print e
except AttributeError, e:
  print e
```